# How I can make a single trigger for both create and update at sqlite3?

Tags: trigger, sqlite3

I made the following table:

```
CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS redirect (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            url_from TEXT not null,
            url_to TEXT not null,
            method TEXT not null,
            http_status_code INTEGER not null CHECK( http_status_code IN (300,301,302,304,304,308,307) ) DEFAULT 301,
            use_in_https INTEGER not null CHECK(use_in_https IN (0,1)) DEFAULT 0,
            use_in_http INTEGER not null CHECK(use_in_http IN (0,1)) DEFAULT 1,
            exact_match INTEGER not null CHECK(exact_match IN (0,1)) DEFAULT 1
        );
```

And I made the following trigger:

```
        CREATE TRIGGER remove_http_https BEFORE INSERT ON redirect BEGIN 
           SELECT CASE WHEN NEW.url_from THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(NEW.url_from,"http:\/\/",""),"https:\/\/","")   END;
        END;
```

But I want the trigger to run at both when I update a value OR insert a value. Is there a way to define a single trigger for both insert and update as sqlite3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible with a single trigger to handle both insert and update.

The CREATE trigger statement on the [graph](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) shows that only one of the DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE can be used.